# How to get new row first in Tableviewcell and new date?

Tags: swift, uitableview, parse-platform, nsdata

Tell me how to do a friend so that when you download from the server a new cell becomes up, The function "insertRow" does not addit ,is not possible to get a row at the top of the table.And when you load a new cell, the dates of the old information become such as when you load a new one that is the same. Tell me how to make sure the date was new and the old one did not change and the cell became at the top of the table.I will be very grateful for any help!!!

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let sportCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "sportCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell


                switch (segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex)  {
            case 0 :



                let soccer = soccerString[indexPath.row]

                sportCell.matchLabel.text = soccer.matchS
                            soccerString[indexPath.row].imagePrS.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil
                    }

                break
            case 1 :

                let basket = basketString[indexPath.row]
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = basket.matchB
                basketString[indexPath.row].imagePrB.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                    sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }
                break
            case 2:
                sportCell.matchLabel.text = tennisString[indexPath.row].matchT

                tennisString[indexPath.row].imagePrT.getDataInBackground {(data, error) in
                        sportCell.imageMatch.image = error == nil ? UIImage(data: data!) : nil

                }
               break
            default:
                break

                }
            sportCell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none

            let date = Date()
            let calendar = Calendar.current



            let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

            dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
            dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru_UA")
            dateFormatter.doesRelativeDateFormatting = true


            if let today = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 0, to: date) {
                let todayString = dateFormatter.string(from: today)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = todayString

            } else if let yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: date) {
                let yesterdayString = dateFormatter.string(from:yesterday)
                sportCell.dataSave.text = yesterdayString
            } else {
                sportCell.dataSave.text = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

            }



                return sportCell
 }
```

Comment: "The function "insertRow" does not addit ,is not possible to get a row at the top of the table" Where is that code?

Comment: how should it look? I do not understand? It's not in soccerString[index.row]?